# Using a ListFragment with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-listfragment, rss-reader, navigation-drawer

I am trying to use the Navigation Drawer with my RSS Reader app. Previously I had multiple tabs with ListFragments to display the parsed feeds. I am just using Googles sample at the moment (Found here: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) but am running into an issue when trying to use a ListFragment.

```
 private void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    RSSFragment fragment = new RSSFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mCategoryTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

In this method it tells me that I cannot use the replace method with ListFragments. So what should I be using instead to make this work?

Comment: What is the minimum Android version you are supporting in your app?

Comment: If your supporting older versions, then your using the wrong `FragmentManager`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like ListFragments cannot be used with the Navigation Drawer. However I was able to convert them to normal Fragments with a ListView and it works just fine.

Comment: Yes you can actually use a `ListFragment` with the `DrawerLayout`