# ListView in Fragment with navigation drawer -Drawer does not pull out over the listview

Tags: listview, android-listview, android-fragments, navigation

I am trying to make a navigation drawer as explained here https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html , I have the drawer ready I am able to plug in my test fragments which have just text views.

Next, I want to have a fragment which has listView that populated from db.  I am able to make listview show up But the Navigation drawer doest pull out over this listview.

I read earlier posts : [Using a ListFragment with Navigation Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003065/using-a-listfragment-with-navigation-drawer?rq=1) based on which i converted ListFragment to fragment and used listview instead of ListFragment.

But still I am not able to have navigation drawer pulled over ..

public class WelcomeScreen extends Fragment {

```
private static final String KEY_SUBJ = "Subjects";
private DBHelper myDBCopier;
Context mycontext;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome, container, false);
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mycontext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

    //code copies the db 
    myDBCopier = new DBHelper(mycontext);
        try {

            myDBCopier.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("PROBLEM");
        }finally{
            System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        }
        myDBCopier.open();

        // this code gets the list

        String[] ListOfSubjects = new String[myDBCopier.rowcountsubj()];

        Cursor MyC = myDBCopier.getSubj();
        int i = 0;
        while(MyC.moveToNext()){
            String uname = MyC.getString(MyC.getColumnIndex(KEY_SUBJ));
            ListOfSubjects[i] = uname;
            System.out.println(uname);
            i++;
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                ListOfSubjects
                );

        // referencing the listview
            ListView myList = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_view);
            myList.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
```

Here is my xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am editing the question after I figured out my mistake ( to make the question and the solution usable)

Following is a part of my activity class where I displayed the fragment

```
.......
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Fragment frag0 = new WelcomeScreen();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, frag0);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
........
```

and here is my main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my main.xml  I had :   .. the placehoder for my New fragment which I wanted to display

so my code should be

`fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, frag0);` ( to specifically place my fragment in container.

instead of

```
 fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, frag0);
```

Ans that is the reason I wasn't able to see the overlaying ListView ( The navigation drawer ) as my new fragment replaced the whole view.